# voip notification not coming when the app is inactive for around 8 hours

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, voip

I am building a group calling app and using **ionic3** for the same. I am using **voIP notification** when the app is in background on inactive in ios. Everything works fine and as expected. The problem I am facing is when the app is in background or inactive for around 8 hours, I do not receive the voIP notification and hence app doesn't wakes up.
i am just a beginner in iOS development so It would be a great help if anyone could help me figure out this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you receive payload, you have to schedule local notification with sound file.

You can also debug is your app crashing in background or killed state.

About 8 hours or any hours, ideally there is no issue when your integration is perfect.

Keep whatsapp in background for 2 days, then make incoming call to that whatsapp, it will notify you.

[Refer more information about VOIP integration](https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification)